# Using cargo build --manifest-path results to greatly increases WASM binary size

Tags: webassembly, rust-cargo, nearprotocol

I am building the same Cargo.toml with two different command-lines. This is for building NEAR protocol smart contracts.

First using `--manifest-path`

```sh
cargo build --manifest-path contract/Cargo.toml --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

```
...
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 23.25s
```

```sh
ls -lha contract/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release
```

```
...
-rwxr-xr-x   2 moo staff 1.7M Oct  5 12:32 nep9000_pool.wasm*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 moo staff 1.8M Oct  5 12:32 nep9000_token.wasm*
```

The size of a binary is 1.8 megabytes.

Then I execute the cargo build from within the folder where the `Cargo.toml` is.

```sh
cd contract 
cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

```
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 22.85s
```

```sh
ls -lha target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release
```

```
-rwxr-xr-x   2 moo staff 127K Oct  5 12:35 nep9000_pool.wasm*
-rw-r--r--   1 moo staff  305 Sep 30 21:09 nep9000_token.d
-rwxr-xr-x   2 moo staff 189K Oct  5 12:35 nep9000_token.wasm*
```

Binary size is 10x smaller in the latter method.

Why is this? How do the `cargo` commands above differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the second build picks up compilation flags `-C link-arg=-s` and the first one does not. Compilation flags can be passed in multiple ways: [as env variable](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/flags.sh) or as part of [.cargo/config](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/2f5b6d91f04fece4fb5a362700ca85d7aa99fcb6/examples/mission-control/.cargo/config). It can be rather exhausting trying to figure out why cargo ignored it in the first place, I just recommend compiling it always as `RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=-s" cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`